# Accessed stale local reference passing short[] from JNI to Java

Tags: java, android, callback, java-native-interface

Hello I'm writing a program for Android with Java and JNI.

I'm caching JavaVM*, a global ref `jclass` and 2 `methodsID` in the `onLoad()`.

Then from `myCallback()`, which is running on a separate thread, I get the ref to the environment using `AttachCurrentThread()` and the cashed JavaVM*. 
Then I want to pass a `short[]` back to Java.

I'm getting the error: `"accessed stale local reference"`

here's my code:

```
JavaVM* mVm = NULL;
static jclass globalJavaReceiver = NULL;
jmethodID updatePlayerStatus = NULL;
jmethodID sendWaveData = NULL;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {

    mVm = vm;

    JNIEnv* env;
    jclass nativeReceiver = NULL;

    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    nativeReceiver = (*env)->FindClass(env,
            "com/example/customviewcircles/nativeaudio/NativeReceiver");

    if (nativeReceiver != NULL) {

        globalJavaReceiver = (jclass)(*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, nativeReceiver);

        if (globalJavaReceiver != NULL) {

            updatePlayerStatus = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, globalJavaReceiver,
                    "myMethodName", "(I)V");

            sendWaveData = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, globalJavaReceiver,
                    "mySecondMethosName", "([S)V");
        }
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void myCallback(SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf bq, void *context) {

        JNIEnv* env;

        (*mVm)->AttachCurrentThread(mVm, &env, NULL);

        jshortArray javaArray = (*env)->NewShortArray(env, myBufferSize);
        if (javaArray != NULL) {

            (*env)->SetShortArrayRegion(env, javaArray, 0, myBufferSize,
                    myNativeShortArray);

        } 

        jobject myObject = NULL;

        if (globalJavaReceiver != NULL) {

            if (sendWaveData != NULL) {

                myObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, globalJavaReceiver,
                        sendWaveData);

                if (myObject != NULL) {

                    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, myObject, sendWaveData,
                            javaArray);

                    // getting error 
                    // JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale local reference 0x40995ec1 (index 22448 in a table of size 2)
                    // VM aborting
                    // A/libc(9813): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 9840 (AudioRecord)
                }
            }
        }
        (*mVm)->DetachCurrentThread(mVm);

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

thank you for your time

Comment: The error message you included in the comment has a slightly strange value for the local reference. You may want to try logging the values of the arguments to the function that's failing to see which one matches the value in the error message, then examine that argument's history carefully.  Also, are you actually passing `sendWaveData` as the constructor argument to `NewObject`?

Comment: I've tried logginf the %p of the arguments but no one matches that local reference id...sendWaveData is the methodID which I retrive in the onLoad() using GetMethodID() and then stored in a global variable

Comment: Unless `sendWaveData` is a constructor, it should not be passed to `NewObject`. I'm concerned that it's corrupting the managed heap, and causing the subsequent failure.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: @StefanoVuerich , So what was the problem?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer have a look ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that in :

```
  myObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, globalJavaReceiver,
                    sendWaveData);
```

I was trying to create an object from a wrong class function, not from the constructor

So then I change this part in:

```
myObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, globalJavaReceiver,
                nativeReceiverConstructor);
```

where nativeReceiverConstructor is the jmethodID from the class constructor. Then finally I've been able to do:

```
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, myObject, sendWaveData, javaArray);
```

where sendWaveData is the jmethodID from the function I want to call.

To pass the array I've then create a jshortArray and SetShortArrayRegion

Hope it helps